# jQM changePage and back button Issue for automatic redirection

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using change page for page redirection

```
$.mobile.changePage('../user/user_dashboard.html');
```

Then i have back button in the pages

```
<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right backFun" data-theme='a'>Back</a>
```

Here my problem is.

consider the pages are 1 & 2

Now im going from 1 to 2. Then came back from 2 to 1 by back button. Then going from 1 to 2, then from 2 to 1 by back button.

So this time, page is redirected from 1 to 2 automatically.

In 1 & 2 pages im using

```
e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
```

Still same issue
What is the solution of this one?